# Dashboard Filter Superset

Tags: python, apache-superset

I have a test data table (called "eu") with around 5 millions Observations, where each Observation belongs a country in the EU. Now I'd like to implement a country filter on my dashboard for further Analysis.

There already exists a filter widget, which does a query on my data set "eu" to get distinct Countries. However, I already know the Country names for the filter and I could skip (if possible) the query. Is there a possibility to set a filter without a query?

The filter would look like:
DE (where Country='DE')
FR (where Country='FR')
etc.
EU without DE (where Country!='DE')

Answer (score 2):

I found a possibility to create a fast filter.

A table 'fcountry' is created, where all countries (DE,FR, etc.) are stored. This table is used to create the filter widget, which is added to the Dashboard.

However, I'm still looking for a handy solution for EU without DE (where Country!='DE'). At the Moment I need to select all the countries except DE.